# Visualizing a single string of text in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, visualization, kibana, kibana-4, metric

In Kibana, I have an index that looks like as follows

- `type` (String)
- `value` (String)
- `timestamp` (Date)

I would like to have a visualization that shows the most recent `value` field where the `type` is equal to "battery", for example.

I would like the visualization to be similar to the "Metric" one, but displaying a string of text instead of a number, of course.

Is this possible with Kibana? If not, how can I get a similar result?

Comment: seems that there's an issue https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/6877

Comment: and this issue is original https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/678

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a Data Table visualization.

In the search query you would specify `type: "Battery"`

In the metric section you would specify `Max timestamp`

In the Split Rows section you would specify `Aggregation=Terms, Field=value, OrderBy=metric:Max timestamp, Order=descending, Size=1`

You will have a result that is a table with 1 row and 2 columns, one of which being a `value` and the other a `timestamp`

If this does not satisfy your needs, you may look into available Kibana plugins that allow new visualizations (see the [list of known plugins](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/wiki/Known-Plugins)) or modify one of them to suite your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this doesn't exactly look like I wanted, but it's better than nothing. Is there any way I could hide the date on the Date Table visualization?

Comment: I was asking the same question from Elasticsearch team in the past. At that point of time the answer was "no". However, Kibana team was working on allowing custom visualizations. Google now tells me that it's possible to create custom kibana visualizations using plugins (example - http://logz.io/blog/kibana-visualizations/), even though I haven't tried it myself

Comment: updated answer with a link to known kibana visualization plugins